# Sharepoint Approval Workflow - Task Approval sent to Directory List - Task Email not Sending

Tags: sharepoint-designer, workflow, approval-process

Created a Approval Workflow as follows:

```
Start **Approval Process** process on **Current Item** with **PT.KT.Admin**
```

Here PT.KT.Admin is a DL used by me.. which has approximately 16 members.

When i run this Approval worklflow NO task email is dropped to this DL.
But if i assign only one person the Task email is dropped.

Reason? Solution anyone? ASAP. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This is not a SharePoint issue rather an Exchange server issue. To resolve do following on the exchange server

1. Exchange Management Console
2. Recipient Configuration
3. Distribution Groups
4. Right click the group `PT.KT.Admin`
5. Select Properties
6. Mail Flow Settings
7. Open property for "Message Delivery Restrictions"
8. Uncheck - Require that all senders are authenticated.